# C/C++ highlight.js not consistent with #ifdef preprocessor defines

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Can the new hightlight.js be fixed to treat preprocessor directives consistently? Currently if you have multiple `#ifdef` statements, highlight.js colors the first, but not others, e.g.

[image]

This is from [Ignoring numbers with letters around them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217429/ignoring-numbers-with-letters-around-them/64217643#64217643). If you look, the first `#ifdef DEBUG` has syntax highlighting applied while the next two are have no syntax highlighting. Shouldn't they all be treated the same?

Comment: *Can the new hightlight.js be fixed to treat preprocessor directives consistently?* That is something you’ll need to put to the maintainers of hightlight.js, see the FAQ is dupe-closed your post to.

Comment: Okay, so this is a closed "WONT-FIX" from a StackExchange standpoint? And now the users are supposed to fix the highlighter StackExhange chose? Understand, I'm not using `highlight.js` in some project I have. I'm talking about how it renders on StackOverflow. It seems a bit odd that the answer would be "go seek out and find the maintainers of the highlight.js we use so you can fix our site for us?" Really?

Comment: Yes, really, and fixes in that project will eventually be deployed here. Just like bugs in other dependencies would be handled.

Comment: How highlight.js renders a code block marked as C exactly the same anywhere you use it, not just on Stack Overflow. This is not a bug in the way Stack Overflow is using the library.

Comment: It’s great you want to help, and it is appreciated that you do. So let us help by directing you to the right place to report this issue. It’ll not get to the folks that can actually make good use of your report, otherwise.

Comment: *about SE. -- But yes, that's SE's policy.

Comment: @10Rep: take into account you can't see deleted comments.

Comment: The epitome of how backwards this approach is -- is that users cannot complete the bug reports at github for highlight.js. Why? The bug reports asks how you have implemented and configured highlight.js and whether AUTO mode is involved. The only people who know that are those who have implemented highlight.js for StackExchange. That is why, what should have happened, is that StackExhchange elevate this bug upsteam reported by someone who know how StackExchange has implemented and configured highlight.js. Instead, the user filed bug is subject to closer for not providing it - nothing gets fixed

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin as noticed before the Highlight.js tries to have a context-sensitive highlighter... additionally it is highlighting C code as C++! And you cannot do a context-sensitive highlighter for C++ because of the macros, defines and types are unknown...

Comment: Thank you @AnttiHaapala. I wanted to see the differences, so I installed both `prettify` and `highlight.js` on one of my servers to check the behaviors. When using `C` (actually autodetect in both cases) The multiple `#ifdef DEBUG` statements are handled correctly. So I don't know why the output is this way on StackOverflow? I simply downloaded the .zip package from [highlightjs.org](https://highlightjs.org/download/) and it works fine. Though the limitations of highlight.js trying to have a `"limited set of classes that work for all languages"` becomes apparent quickly.

Comment: I believe we got this one resolved: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2737

@DavidC.Rankin [Current Highight.js maintainer here] Very recently we fully split our single `cpp` grammar into C and C++ grammars so if contributors are willing to help those two grammars can now diverge to highlight both C and C++ better.  I'm not sure SE will choose to load both grammars but there should only be a small penalty for doing so since they share so much in common.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala We do try to be as context-insensitive as possible.  And yes C++ is hard because of macros, templates, etc...

Comment: And you've just highlighted why bugs should be posted on GitHub properly; https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3040 now links to more information in a question you've deleted. Note that when you talk about *"version mismatches between SO and github"* (or post e.g. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2973#issuecomment-766261226) you should be aware that GitHub *doesn't use highlight.js*, which is why the issue template explicitly suggests that you can use GitHub's highlighting as the expected behaviour, and suggests screenshots or a fiddle for the MRE.